# Moving camera via WASD buttons

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I control the camera in Forge Viewer with WAST keys?

I've tried something like this.

```
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'));
        viewer.start();
        
        addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 87) {
                console.log("W pressed")
                camera = viewer.getCamera()
                camera.translateZ(50)
                viewer.applyCamera(camera)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed object for EventListener, it should be:

1. typescript:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event)=>{});
```

2. javascript:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', (event)=>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the key press events, I would rather suggest you experiment a bit with HotKeyManger.
Something like this should work:

```js
const hotkeys = [{
    keycodes: [
        Autodesk.Viewing.KeyCode.w
    ],
    onRelease: (e) => console.log("Just pressed the W")
},{
    keycodes: [
        Autodesk.Viewing.KeyCode.s
    ],
    onRelease: (e) => console.log("Just pressed the S")
},{
    keycodes: [
        Autodesk.Viewing.KeyCode.a
    ],
    onRelease: (e) => console.log("Just pressed the A")
},{
    keycodes: [
        Autodesk.Viewing.KeyCode.d
    ],
    onRelease: (e) => console.log("Just pressed the D")
}];


let manager  = this.viewer.getHotkeyManager()

manager.pushHotkeys("HZ",hotkeys)
```

As the name implies, it is for hotkeys, but works just fine for single keys, too.